# upload an image to mysql from android

Tags: php, android, mysql

THe only problem i am having is that when i add my image that is a jpeg, its type in my database is application / octet stream?

How do i make it stay as a jpeg in my database?

Comment: Store only image metadata in the database (mime type, extension, date when it's been uploaded, name, size, path etc). Store the image itself (the binary file) in the file system. That is recommended way to store media. There is a BLOB column type in MySQL and yes, it has certain advantages compared to filesystem, but I would recommend storing only very small images in the database itself (like icons, small avatars). Any larger images would be just a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling uploads, it is generally not a good idea to store files directly in the database.  Even though there is a type of field that can store such data, your database will quickly become large and slower to query.

When handling image uploads, your best bet is to keep the image as a file on the sever and store the path in the database.  You'd use php's `move_uploaded_file` function (check out the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)), then put the `$destination` variable you used in `move_uploaded_file` into the database as just another piece of text.

**Edit**:  If you still want to store the images in the database, I will remind you again that it is a bad, bad, bad idea, you will have to create a system that is dedicated to retrieving the data and outputting it as an image.  For instance, this file would be called getimage.php:

```
<?php 
    @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or
        die('Database error');
    @mysql_select_db("upload");

    $id = isset($_GET['image_id') ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['image_id']) : false;

    if ($id === false)
        die('Invalid image id');

    $q = @mysql_query("SELECT img_data, mime_type FROM table_name WHERE id = ".$id);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);

    if (!row)
        die('Image not found');

    header("Content-type: ".$row['mime_type']);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    die($row['img_data']);
?>
```

You then use that as your image src:

```
<img src="getimage.php?image_id=1" />
```

Comment: i know the database isnt the best way to store the file, but i do still need to know how to do it